# Torah is a Watching

Tags: vaeschanan, parshanut-torah-comment

The Posuk says

> ושמרתם ועשיתם כי היא חכמתכם ובינתכם לעיני העמים

To which Rashi Comments:

> 'ושמרתם' זו משנה

**Reb Moshe Feinstein** in **Darash Moshe** asks why is it that the torah is referd to as a watching?

Comment: Drush aside, (or at least drush d'drush), the drasha is saying that "you shall observe" refers to the halakhic corpus which facilitates observance. Are you looking for something else? Is this an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He answers that Torah is something that must be learnt by a *Rebbi* it must be watched in a sense if you use your own logic you are liable to make errors in judgment which would put the whole Torah in question. Therefore it must be watched given over from a *Rebbi* to *talmid* as if left to ones own intellect it may happen as that what happened to the generation of *Enosh* who came to the understanding that they should not worship g-d but his servants in the Heavens as they listen to their own intellect and not their elders *Adam* and *Sheis*.